# Examples of user-entered code that would cause an issue

Tags: python

Let's say the user has installed a python interpreter **on their machine/browser**, for example, using something like https://github.com/iodide-project/pyodide. I understand not allowing someone to enter in arbitrary code when they don't own the resources, for example doing something like:

```
exec('while 1: os.fork()')
```

However, if the user is executing the code on their own machine, is there anything wrong with allowing them to run arbitrary `eval`s and `exec`s, and just telling them "Please use at your own risk"? The use case is we give the user an environment to work with a spreadsheet, and they can enter in formulas using python, and we just 'pass-through' the entered string (in the spreadsheet cell) to their python environment.

Comment: You might get better answers for this question on [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is there a use case for the user to call `eval` and `exec`?

Comment: @Pynchia anything they enter into the cell is inferred as a formula, i.e., valid python code that is to be executed to produce a result for that cell. (Think of the cell as a python interpreter behind-the-scenes with access to the other values in the row as `locals()`)

Comment: @snakecharmerb well I mean if they're typing in python code...I'd imagine (hope?) they'd have a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with the user being able to run arbitrary Javascript code client side (which is true for all websites), it should be also OK for them to run arbitrary code with Pyodide. Both are sandboxed by the browser.

For instance, they won't be able to interact with their actual file system, nor generally make any system calls that don't pass through the Webassembly VM. See https://webassembly.org/docs/security/ for more details.

Comment: thanks for this. In that case, what is considered the "root" filesystem that the user has access to. Does the sandbox just create its own sandboxed filesystem for the user to be able to manipulate?

Comment: Yes, it uses an in memory filesystem (MEMFS) that's re-created on each page load, so there is no risk in doing anything with it. https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html#memfs